# Is double negation deconstruction applied to all branches of a truth tree?

Tags: logic

If I am making a truth tree and already working on two branches when I come across a double negation (eg. ~~A), do I just decompose it to A right where it is, or do I add A to all branches? Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: NO; the rules have to be applied one by one to every single branch. Thus, you can add A to every branch where ~~A occurs.

Comment: So if there's a branch without ~~A, I don't add A to it, right?

Comment: Exactly.........